# Trying to solve the Solidity security challenge

Tags: solidity, security, smart-contract-wallets

I know how to get the address inside the list, but I don't understand how to make a signed message containing my name and the signature (from an address stored in winners.

**Here is the code:**

```
pragma solidity 0.8.10;

// The goal of this challenge is to be able to sign offchain a message

// with an address stored in winners.
contract Challenge{

    address[] public winners;
    bool lock;

    function exploit_me(address winner) public{
        lock = false;

        msg.sender.call("");

        require(lock);
        winners.push(winner);
    }

    function lock_me() public{
        lock = true;
    }
}
```